# No value associated with key CodingKeys

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

I'm trying to parse the following json:

```
"categories": [
        {
            "id": 42,
            "name": "Air Conditioning",
            "image_url": "system-data/category/Category-AirConditioning.png",
            "image_marker_url": "system-data/category/Marker_Category-Air Conditioning.png",
            "status_id": 7,
            "created_at": 1580452213,
            "updated_at": 1580452213
        },
        {
            "id": 43,
            "name": "Car Wash",
            "image_url": "system-data/category/Category-Carwash.png",
            "image_marker_url": "system-data/category/Marker_Category-Car Wash.png",
            "status_id": 7,
            "created_at": 1580452213,
            "updated_at": 1580452213
        },
        {
            "id": 45,
            "name": "Automobile Services",
            "image_url": "system-data/category/Category-Automobile.png",
            "image_marker_url": "system-data/category/Marker_Category-Automobile Services.png",
            "status_id": 7,
            "created_at": 1580452213,
            "updated_at": 1580452213
        },
        {
            "id": 48,
            "name": "Electrical",
            "image_url": "system-data/category/Category-Electrical.png",
            "image_marker_url": "system-data/category/Marker_Category-Electrical.png",
            "status_id": 7,
            "created_at": 1580452213,
            "updated_at": 1580452213
        },
        {
            "id": 49,
            "name": "Generator Repair & Maintenance",
            "image_url": "system-data/category/Category-Generator.png",
            "image_marker_url": "system-data/category/Marker_Category-Generator Repair & Maintenance.png",
            "status_id": 7,
            "created_at": 1580452213,
            "updated_at": 1580452213
        }
    ]
```

Below is my struct to map the json reponse into model:

```
struct CityCategory: Codable{

    let id: Int
    let name, imageUrl, imageMarkerUrl: String
    let statusID, createdAt, updatedAt: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case imageUrl = "image_url"
        case imageMarkerUrl = "image_marker_url"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case statusID = "status_id"
    }

}

struct CityCategoryResponse: Codable{
    let cityCat: [CityCategory]
}
```

I'm trying this:

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(CityCategoryResponse.self, from: jsonData)
```

and it throws error.

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "cityCat", intValue: nil),
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
>   value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"cityCat\",
>   intValue: nil) (\"cityCat\").", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
let categories: [CityCategory]
```

or

```
struct CityCategoryResponse: Codable{
    let cityCat: [CityCategory] 

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case cityCat = "categories" 
    }
}
```

> `cityCat` isn't a key inside your json , hence the decoder can't find it

Comment: you have to write properties that match json keys or use `enum CodingKeys` for custom key names