# How to fix no value associated with key CodingKeys error when parsing JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to parse data from an API using swift.

**JSON**

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [{
        "id": 597,
        "overview": "101-year-old...",
        "title": "Titanic"
    }, {
        "id": 598,
        "overview": "Another one...",
        "title": "Titanic II"
    }, {
        "id": 599,
        "overview": "Another one...",
        "title": "Titanic III"
    }]
}
```

**Model**

```
import SwiftUI

struct APIResult: Codable {
    var data: APIMovieData
}

struct APIMovieData: Codable {
    var count: Int
    var results: [Movie]
}

struct Movie: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var overview: String
}
```

**View Model**

```
func searchMovies(){
  
        let originalQuery = searchQuery.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
        let url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=XXXXc&query=\(originalQuery)"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in

            if let error = err{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            guard let APIData = data else{
                print("no data found")
                return
            }
            
            do{
                
                // decoding API Data....
                
                let movies = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResult.self, from: APIData)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    if self.fetchedMovies == nil{
                        self.fetchedMovies = movies.data.results
                    }
                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
```

But when I run my app the search fails with:

> debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil) ("data").", underlyingError: nil))

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969883/no-value-associated-with-key-codingkeys) it seems like the problem is my model doesn't match the JSON structure. But what would be the right way to structure my Model for the JSON?

Comment: `But what would be the right way to structure my Model for the JSON?`: You can use https://app.quicktype.io or use custom `init(from:)` to parse your JSON into your target struct. Else, you could also do the reverse. Create a `APIResult` with "enough" values, then call `JSONEncoder()` and see what looks like the generated JSON, and how it differs from the JSON you got. It might help you understand the whole structure and how "matching" works (after all, there is no magic, it's logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, your JSON structure needs to map your Codable elements. For example, your Codable starts with `data`, which isn't represented in the JSON structure at all. There also isn't any `count` in your JSON.

```
let jsonData = """
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [{
        "id": 597,
        "overview": "101-year-old...",
        "title": "Titanic"
    }, {
        "id": 598,
        "overview": "Another one...",
        "title": "Titanic II"
    }, {
        "id": 599,
        "overview": "Another one...",
        "title": "Titanic III"
    }]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct APIResult: Codable {
    var page: Int
    var results: [Movie]
}

struct Movie: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var overview: String
    var title: String
}

do {
    let apiResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResult.self, from: jsonData)
    let movies = apiResult.results
    print(movies)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```